# yii2 how can I use REST UrlRule inside GroupUrlRule

Tags: routes, yii2

I have the following GroupUrlRule:

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\web\GroupUrlRule',
    'prefix' => '_api',
    'routePrefix' => '',
    'rules' => [
        'GET /v1/users' => 'v1/user/list',
        'GET /v1/users/<id:\w+>' => 'v1/user/view'
     ]
]
```

This doesn't work for some reason. However, if I use the following inside the main URLManager rules:

```
'GET _api/v1/users' => /v1/user/list',
'GET _api/v1/users/<id:\w+>' => 'v1/user/view'
```

The routes works. I don't understand why the same routes don't work inside GroupUrlRule. How can I make the routes to work with GroupUrlRule?

Comment: isn't [yii\rest\UrlRule](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rest-urlrule.html) (instead of `yii\web\UrlRule`) the one you are looking for ?

Comment: \rest\UrlRule creates all the urls for you based on controller but I want to specifically choose which ones I want. And this is allowed by UrlRule.. but for some reason it doesn't work inside groupurlrule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging into Yii2 API and source code, I finally found the problem. GroupUrlRoute adds the prefix at the beginning of the array key, without testing what the key is. That's why I tried to see if there are any additional parameters in UrlRoute that might help, which there is:

```
 ['class' => 'yii\web\GroupUrlRoute',
  'prefix' => '_api/v1',
  'routePrefix' => 'v1',
  'rules' => [
      ['pattern' => 'users',
       'route' => 'user/list',
       'verb' => 'GET'
       // if you need multiple, you can use array like ['GET', 'POST']
       ]
  ]
 ]
```